# Redirecionamento de domínio em arquivo .htaccess

Tags: htaccess

Eu tenho um domínio assim: `https://www.dominio.com`, que sempre tem que acessar dessa forma.

Então preciso fazer uns redirecionamentos. São esses:

De:

```
(http) www.dominio.com.br
(http) www.dominio.com
https://www.dominio.com.br
```

Para:

`https://www.dominio.com`

O que eu fiz até agora:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?dominio\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?dominio\.com\.br$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://dominio\.com/%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

**O único problema é esse:**

Mas não redireciona quando digito `https://www.dominio.com.br`.

Comment: Não seria só fixar o dominio.com? `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.dominio.com/$1 [L,R=301]`

Comment: Não funcionou. O problema é quando eu digito `https://www.dominio.com.br.`, ele não redireciona e dá aquela página de erro de segurança. Porquê não tem certificado nesse domínio.

Comment: os dois domínios são seus? caso não seja dono do `.com` ele não vai apontar para o seu serviço.

Comment: Os dois são meus, o `.com` e o `.com.br`. Eles são redirecionados para o IP do meu servidor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vamos por partes :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ # REMOVE O www DA FRENTE DO DOMINIO
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.*)\.br$ # REMOVE O br DO FINAL DO DOMINIO
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off # CASO NAO ESTEJA EM https ALTERA PARA POR https
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d # SE O CAMINHO NÃO FOR UM DIETORIO
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f # SE O CAMINHO NÃO APONTA PARA UM ARQUIVO
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L] # QUALQUER REQUISIÇÃO VAI PARA index.php

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Guilherme, não fui eu que negativei. Veja só, editei minha pergunta e coloquei meu .htaccess inteiro. É do Laravel. Fiz o que você falou, mas deu erro no site.

Comment: @DiegoSouza veja a edição, pode ser pelo segundo motivo, tlz invertendo a ordem resolva

Comment: Sua resposta resolveu, mas não foi por causa da ordem. O certificado está instalado no `.com`. O que eu fiz foi retirar as outras condições que o Laravel coloca, igual você fez. Obrigado!

Comment: @DiegoSouza que bom que resolveu :D

Comment: Guilherme, aconteceu um problema que eu descobri. O meu site em uma página /pasta. Quando vai para essa página dá erro de não encontrada. É porquê eu comentei a linha `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`. Tive que descomentar porquê ela é muito importante, daí voltei a estaca 0.

Comment: Alterar em qual linha ?

Comment: Mas já tem essa linha embaixo.

Comment: @DiegoSouza estou fazendo os testes localmente, e esta ok, me mande no pastebin como esta seu htaccess atual

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59987/discussion-between-diego-souza-and-guilherme-lautert).

Comment: @DiegoSouza Alterei novamente, agora testei todas as possibilidades aqui no local e esta ok como conversamos, altera seu `.htaccess` para este e lembre de limpar o cache do navegador ou abrir como privado.

Comment: Sinto muito, mas não foi. Dá erro 500.